# What is the name of this background app notice?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, notice

If I start a Voice Memo on iOS 8, and go to another app (e.g. Notes) then a red notice appears on the top of the screen (see below, "Recording 00:16").

What is the name of this notice? Where is the relevant iOS documentation?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the red bar and what triggers it? or about the various status bars that have double the height of the default status bar?

Comment: The various status bars that have double the height. How many different heights can the status bar have?

Comment: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about double-high status bar, this is caused when some other app is recording audio , fetching background locations , etc  in background , the double height status bar suggests user that the app is using the resource.

You can find relevant docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Multitasking.html)

> Make sure your UI can handle the double-high status bar. The
>   double-high status bar appears during events such as in-progress phone
>   calls, audio recording, and tethering. In unprepared apps the extra
>   height of this bar can cause layout problems. For example, the UI can
>   become pushed down or covered. In a multitasking environment, it’s
>   especially important to be able to handle the double-high status bar
>   properly because there are likely to be more apps that can cause it to
>   appear.