# How to show top bar in the IOS while pressing home button.?

Tags: ios, background

what settings makes this band on top? I am working app, that works on background but it not showing any band/bar like this in the top. I googled it for this, I cannot find the settings for this.

I am seeing this type of band in google navigator, voice recording ..

Please give me some suggestion for me.

[image]

Comment: This comes up automatically when you are using any permitted resource in background like recording audio, location , etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485114/what-is-the-name-of-this-background-app-notice/29485568#29485568

Comment: hi @BhumitMehta , thankyou for you reply. In my app. I am doing background location fetch. "Required background modes" is enabled in my pList. and I am asking "locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true" also. but still it not showing that band. do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: make sure you are requesting with `requestAlwaysAuthorization` and not when in use. Also make sure you are calling 'startLocationUpdates'. It only shows up if location is being accessed at that time

Comment: hi @BhumitMehta , yes I am using while asking location update. but still no luck. :(

Comment: Probably you are also not receiving location updates when in background than, you need to find that reason and status bar will come up.

Comment: Can you confirm it is getting location updates in the background by putting a breakpoint in your background code?

Comment: hi @BhumitMehta , wottle : I am getting location while the app in background mode.

Answer (score 1):

It is the property of `navigationItem`. Use it like this:

```
 self.navigationItem.prompt = @"Your message here";
```

Comment: it is working in when I am in that particular page in the app. I want to know after pressing the home button. it still shows this band on other apps. can you please give me some example links for this?